# Running a process on every combination between files in two folders

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I have two folders where the 1st has 19 .fa files and the 2nd has 37096 .fa files

Files in the 1st folder are named BF_genomea[a-s].fa, and files in the 2nd are named [1-37096]ZF_genome.fa

I have to run this process where lastz filein1stfolder filein2ndfolder [arguments] > outputfile.axt, so that I run every file in the 1st folder against every file in the 2nd folder.

Any sort of output file's naming would serve, as far as it allows for id which particular combination of parent files they came from, and they have extension .axt

This is what I have done so far

```
for file in /tibet/madzays/finch_data/BF_genome_split/*.fa; do for otherfile in /tibet/madzays/finch_data/ZF_genome_split/*.fa; name="${file##*/}"; othername="${otherfile##*/}"; lastz $file $otherfile --step=19 --hspthresh=2200 --gappedthresh=10000 --ydrop=3400 --inner=2000 --seed=12of19 --format=axt --scores=/tibet/madzays/finch_data/BFvsZFLASTZ/HoxD55.q > /home/madzays/qsub/test/"$name""$othername".axt; done; done
```

Comment: The second `for` is missing its `do`. It'd also be much easier to read if it were split it into separate lines (and indent the contents of the loops). Are you having any other problems with it?

Comment: Where would that do go? Actually, yes, I'm having probs indenting it here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad I said in a comment, the inner loop is missing a `do` keyword (`for otherfile in pattern; do` <-- right there). Is this in the form of a script file? If so, you should add a shebang as the first line to tell the OS how to run the script. And break it into multiple lines and indent the contents of the loops, to make it easier to read (and easier to spot problems like the missing `do`).

Off the top of my head, I see one other thing I'd change: the output filenames are going to be pretty ugly, just the two input files mashed together with a ".atx" on the end (along the lines of "BF_genomeac.fa14ZF_genome.fa.axt"). I'd parse the IDs out of the input filenames and then use them to build a more reasonable output filename convention. Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /tibet/madzays/finch_data/BF_genome_split/*.fa; do
    for otherfile in /tibet/madzays/finch_data/ZF_genome_split/*.fa; do
        name="${file##*/}"
        tmp="${name#BF_genomea}"    # remove filename prefix
        id="${tmp%.*}"    # remove extension to get the ID
        othername="${otherfile##*/}"
        otherid="${othername%ZF_genome.fa}"    # just have to remove a suffix here
        lastz $file $otherfile --step=19 --hspthresh=2200 --gappedthresh=10000 --ydrop=3400 --inner=2000 --seed=12of19 --format=axt --scores=/tibet/madzays/finch_data/BFvsZFLASTZ/HoxD55.q > "/home/madzays/qsub/test/BF${id}_${otherid}ZF.axt"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The code can nearly directly been translated from your requierements:

```
base=/tibet/madzays/finch_data
for b in {a..s}
do
  for z in {1..37096}
  do
    lastz $base/BF_genome_split/${b}.fa $base/ZF_genome_split/${z}.fa --hspthresh=2200 --gappedthresh=10000 --ydrop=3400 --inner=2000 --seed=12of19 --format=axt --scores=$base/BFvsZFLASTZ/HoxD55.q > /home/madzays/qsub/test/${b}-${z}.axt
  done
done
```

Note that oneliners easily lead to errors, like missing `do`s, which are then hard to find from the error message (error in line 1).